# T4MVC can't handle two controllers of the same name

Tags: t4mvc

I'm trying to use T4MVC but it doesn't seem to work in my situation of having two controllers of the same name in different namespaces.  I've got the following two controllers:

```
MyNamespace.Api.HomeController  (an ApiController)
MyNamespace.Api.Test.HomeController  (a regular MVC Controller)
```

When I run T4MVC, only the test controller is generated.  If I rename the test controller to something else, then both are generated.  How can I keep my naming convention and get T4MVC to recognize both controllers?

Comment: Would you want T4MVC to ignore one of them, or somehow work with both?

Comment: Also, can you include the specific behavior that you get? e.g. is it some exception? 'Doesn't seem to work' is a bit vague :)